# Locus of hyperbole chords midpoints

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the locus of midpoints of all chords of hyperbole $b^2x^2-a^2y^2=a^2b^2$ that pass through point $A(a,0)$.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The equation of the any straight line passing through $A(a,0)$ is $$\dfrac{y-0}{x-a}=m\iff y=mx-ma$$ where $m$ is the gradient

Put this value of $y$ in $$b^2x^2-a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$  to form a Quadratic Equation in $x$ whose roots represent the [abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa) of the intersection.

So, if the midpoint of the intersection if $P(h,k)$

$$h=\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2$$

Similarly, $k=\dfrac{y_1+y_2}2,$  where $y_i=mx_i-ma;i=1,2$

Now eliminate $m$

Comment: Your set of lines through $A$ doesn’t include $x=a$.